# Youtube Api Sandbox Violation

Tags: actionscript-3, api, youtube, youtube-api, policy

Recently, I notice a sandbox violation message like the one below. It appears to be a cross domain policy issue between youtube.com and s.ytimg.com. I'm not sure but any help would be appreciated.

> *** Security Sandbox Violation ***
>
> SecurityDomain 'xhttps://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3' tried to
>   access incompatible context
>   'xhttps://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/player-vflq_SRd4/apiplayer3.swf'
>
> SecurityError: Error #2121: Security sandbox violation:
>   Loader.content: xhttps://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3 cannot
>   access
>   xhttps://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/player-vflq_SRd4/apiplayer3.swf. This
>   may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.
>
> at flash.display::Loader/get content()  at
>   com.google.youtube.application::SwfProxy/onRequestParameters()    at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   com.google.youtube.model::YouTubeEnvironment()    at
>   com.google.youtube.application::VideoApplication/createYouTubeEnvironment()
>     at
>   com.google.youtube.application::VideoApplication/onLoaderInfoInit()

Code Example from

https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

```
// The player SWF file on www.youtube.com needs to communicate with your host
// SWF file. Your code must call Security.allowDomain() to allow this
// communication.
Security.allowDomain("youtube.com");
Security.allowDomain("s.ytimg.com");

// This will hold the API player instance once it is initialized.
var player:Object;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange", 
        onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the Player API ID 
    trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);

    // Once this event has been dispatched by the player, we can use
    // cueVideoById, loadVideoById, cueVideoByUrl and loadVideoByUrl
    // to load a particular YouTube video.
    player = loader.content;
    // Set appropriate player dimensions for your application
    player.setSize(480, 360);
    player.loadVideoById("M7lc1UVf-VE")
}

function onPlayerError(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the error code
    trace("player error:", Object(event).data);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new player state
    trace("player state:", Object(event).data);
}

function onVideoPlaybackQualityChange(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new video quality
    trace("video quality:", Object(event).data);
}
```

Comment: I have always been inundated with information messages in Flash Builder and Flashdevelop consoles that look like the first line of your error. This is caused by YouTube's poor crossdomain.xml & Flash's unreasonable cross-domain security, but did not affect compilation.

Recently they have turned into error messages that stop compilation. They are the same as yours, also showing the error trace lines. I have not altered any related code or changed Flash version/settings so I suspect it is something YouTube have altered. I notice my error mentions https when I think it should be http.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I wanted to be sure, I'm not missing something new or some type of update. It started a couple of days ago.